# Fields from Django Abstract model are returning None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an abstract django model and a basic model. I am expecting any instance of the basic model to have a value for the field created_at or updated_at. However, as of now, all my instances have None for both these fields. What am I doing wrong?

```
from django.db import models


class Trackable(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Quotation(Trackable):
    reference = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=80)


quotation = Quotation(id=1)
print(quotation.created_at)
>>> None
```

**Edit:** It works with below code (but that does not explain why above code does not work):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class AutoDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        return timezone.now()


class Trackable(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Quotation(Trackable):
    reference = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields evaluate to `None`, because these fields in you Abstract model are only filled when the object is saved in the database. When you only instantiate you model, it does not touch the database, so they have the value of None, unless you call the `save()` method.

Try:

```
quotation = Quotation(id=1)
quotation.save()
print(quotation.created_at)
```

Comment: I actually call save every time in my endpoints. So, I don't think the issue is related to it. I found a way to make it work, I will add it in my answer as well